# How to set column value ends with in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have users Entity which has gmailId property. I want to put the condition that gmail id must ends with gmail.com.

I tried with regex pattern, but its giving an exception saying that

Validation failed for classes [com.ciphercloud.ae.entities.Users] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must match "gmail.com"', propertyPath=gmailId, rootBeanClass=class com.ciphercloud.ae.entities.Users, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}'}
].

What is the annotation to use in hibernate. My Users entity definition looks like

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "gmailId"))

public class Users {

@Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "sequence_user_id", strategy = "com.ciphercloud.ae.generators.UserIdGenerator")
@GeneratedValue(generator = "sequence_user_id")
@Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String user_id;

@Pattern(regexp = "\gmail.com$")
private String gmailId;

private String role;

// all setters and getters
```

Please suggest me how to put the condition that insert value of gmailId should ends with gmail.com using hibernate ????

Comment: You're using the correct annotation, but your regexp pattern is wrong. I think it should be something like: "^.*[gmail.com]+$"

Answer (score 0):

Changing regex to as follows works fine.

```
@Pattern(regexp = ".*(@gmail.com)")
private String gmailId;
```